# How to create graphs or historigrams with mongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I need to make a graph where to show how many total users we have registered in a time interval. (The language is TypeScript but I can get an answer in another language or using the aggregate of mongoDB)

```
Example:

Day 1: 10 total users registered

Day 2: 139 ...

Day 3: 1230 ...

Day 4: 2838 ... 

...

... 

Current day: X number of users ... and so it would end.
```

It should be noted that all users have a field called createAt, which is of type date.

I tried to obtain the users by means of cubes but it is not an optimal solution.

```
const response = await this.userModel.aggregate([
      {
        $bucketAuto: {
          groupBy: '$createdAt',
          buckets: 4,
        },
      },
    ]);
console.log(response);
```

I have also thought about using mapReduce from mongoDB and pass the specified function to it. But in terms of performance, I would like to know if that could create the pipelines simply with aggregate. mapReduce would be a second option (slightly slower) and as a last option to get all the users (only with the CreateAt field) and process them in my backend.

Thank you in advance for your answers

**Update**

I also mean that with autoBucket it orders them by non-specific time intervals, it basically orders them by the number of users and groups them by the creation dates, also when i passed the dates to mongodb, with `$bucket` the result is not as expected

[$bucketAuto Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7s4i.png)

[$bucket option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEFgU.png)

input Example:

```
const list = [
    {
        "createdAt": "2021-08-30T23:47:16.663Z",
        "_id": "612d6e044007a95446848cef"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2021-08-31T04:18:11.820Z",
        "_id": "612dad830541fa001bb63671"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2021-08-31T04:18:47.794Z",
        "_id": "612dada70541fa001bb63674"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2021-08-31T04:20:14.415Z",
        "_id": "612dadfe0541fa001bb63678"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2021-08-31T04:22:45.580Z",
        "_id": "612dae950541fa001bb63682"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2021-08-31T11:24:28.471Z",
        "_id": "612e116c0541fa001bb63688"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2021-08-31T18:47:09.452Z",
        "_id": "612e792dba2a3e1d081c9f3d"
    }
];
```

Comment: Have a look at [$bucket()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/), there you can set bucket boundaries according to your needs. What do you mean by "but it is not an optimal solution"?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit With the bucket option I tried to pass a couple of dates but I did not get the expected result, as for optimal solutions, I mean processing speed. since it would not be very convenient to process all the data in the backend (for example, if we are talking about 4k-100k users) when it could be obtained through aggregate or mapReduce from the database

Comment: Without showing any sample input data and expected result, it will be very difficult to provide any answers.

Comment: MongoDB Atlas Charts allows you to embed a chart into your own web app.  https://docs.mongodb.com/charts/saas/embed-chart-anon-auth/#std-label-anon-embedding-charts